# Load Textarea text into input boxes

Tags: jquery, html

For my website, users can provide a list of tracks.
So far it works, However I wish to feature a textarea to textbox function

So people copy paste from a textfile into a textarea, where the convert button reads that text and places the proper artist/track in a inputbox

So if a user puts in:

```
Artist1 - Track1
Artist2 - Track2
Artist3 - Track3
Artist4 - Track4
```

The jquery code should place these into input boxes where Artist and Track are separated.

[image: Current Layout]
How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job.  No need for a convert button.  Just listen for the `input` event:

```js
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
  var sp= this.value.split(/[\r\n]/);
  sp.forEach(function(value, i) {
    var sp= value.split(/ *- */);
    $('.Artists tr').eq(i).find('input').eq(0).val(sp[0]);
    $('.Artists tr').eq(i).find('input').eq(1).val(sp[1]);
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 90%;
  height: 6em;
}

.Artists td:nth-child(1):before {
  content: 'Artist';
  display: block;
  font: 9px verdana;
  color: brown;
}

.Artists td:nth-child(2):before {
  content: 'Track';
  display: block;
  font: 9px verdana;
  color: brown;
}

input {
  width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>

<table class="Artists">
  <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td>
  <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td>
  <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td>
  <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td>
  <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td>
  <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td>
  <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td>
  <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td>
  <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td>
  <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td>
</table>
```

Comment: This works near perfectly thank you!
However, It does not seperate on '-'

How can I achieve this? So it will split on "whitespace - whitespace"

Comment: It should split when there are *zero* or more spaces on either side of the hyphen.  Do you prefer it to split when there are *one* or more spaces?

Comment: It should specifically split on "whitespace '-' whitespace"
Now it only splits if there is a '-' without whitespace next to either sides

Comment: By "whitespace," are you including tabs, or just the space bar?

Comment: All whitespace preferably, so if the pasted text is Artist1 - Track2
The inputboxes will be filled Artist1 (left box) Track2 (right box)

Comment: What happens if you paste Artist1 - Track2 into the textarea in my example?  On my computer, they go in separate boxes.

Comment: My apologies, Indeed is was for a normal dash (-), the type I tried to paste had a different dash (–), which I've added to the replace list.